# Бот не отвечает на команды, но он в сети

Tags: python, discord.py

Бот запускается, бот в сети, но не отвечает на команды

````
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='..', intents=intents)

# Словарь для хранения предупреждений пользователей
warnings = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')
    print('Bot is ready to work!')

@bot.command(name='ping')
async def ping(ctx):
    """Показать пинг бота"""
    latency = round(bot.latency * 1000)
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! Мой пинг: {latency}ms')

@bot.command(name='timeout')
async def timeout(ctx, member: discord.Member, duration: int, *, reason: str):
    """Кидать пользователя в тайм-аут"""
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.ban_members:
        await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Тайм-аут"))
        await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} отправлен в тайм-аут на {duration} минут по причине: {reason}')
        await asyncio.sleep(duration * 60)
        await member.remove_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Тайм-аут"))
    else:
        await ctx.send("У вас нет разрешения на это действие.")

@bot.command(name='warn')
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason: str):
    """Выдать предупреждение пользователю"""
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.ban_members:
        if member.id not in warnings:
            warnings[member.id] = []
        warnings[member.id].append(reason)
        await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} получил предупреждение по причине: {reason}')
        
        # Проверяем количество предупреждений пользователя
        if len(warnings[member.id]) >= 3:
            await member.ban(reason="Достигнуто максимальное количество предупреждений (3)")
            del warnings[member.id]
    else:
        await ctx.send("У вас нет разрешения на это действие.")

# Запустите бота
bot.run('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN')```
````